# Velocity #foreach not working as expected with string passed as $value variable

Tags: java, string, foreach, velocity

I haven't used Velocity much recently but something that I was certain used to work isn't working now - the only difference that I can think of since I've last used it and now is that we upgraded from v1.6.4 to v1.7.

In our Java code we add a values to the script context that is a comma separated string along the lines of;

```
context.put("value", "'a','b','c'")
```

(this has been simplified for the example).

In my velocity code if I say things like;

```
$value -- it prints 'a','b','c'
$value.split(",")[0] -- it prints 'a'
$value.split(",").size() -- it prints 3
```

However, if I try saying

```
#foreach ( $val in $value.split(",") )
  -- $val
#end
```

It doesn't print anything.  In fact, if I say

```
#set ( $val = $value.split(",") ) 
#if ( ! $val ) 
  -- print null message here
#end
```

It enters the if block and says that $val is null.

At one point I thought I would be clever and do something along the lines of the following

```
#set ( $count = $value.split(",").size() )
#foreach ( $item in [0..$count] )
   -- reference $value.split(",")[$item]
#end
```

but it simply doesn't want to use the RHS of anything derived from $value.

Finally, if I do the following;

```
#set ( $value = "'a','b','c'" )
#foreach ( $val in $value.split(",") ) 
  -- Write out $val
#end
```

It works exactly as expected.  There's something about passing it into the engine as a variable that is preventing it from being processed correctly.

Anyone have any idea why this isn't working?  Any possible workarounds?

Thanks in advance,

p.s.

Comment: Are you sure there's no simple answer like "there's a typo in the variable name"? It should indeed work, and it works for me in a simple test.

Comment: Your statement "There's something about passing it into the engine as a variable that is preventing it from being processed correctly." seems a likely explanation because I couldn't get it to work either unless I did the `split` to the right of the `in`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a list into the context for foreach to work, as in:

```
context.put("value", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

Comment: Thanks but not quite the answer I'm looking for.  If that were strictly true, the last example wouldn't work either but it does...  split() returns a String Array which should be iterable - there are countless examples of this on the web but I can't determine if any of them were done with v1.7...